# Can I select the main mission in my Pip-Boy?

Tags: fallout-4

I have been pursuing various side missions and want to get back on track and play the main mission or main story, whatever you want to call it.

Is there a way to tell which is the main story in quests on my Pip-Boy?

Comment: The main story is actually a chain of about a dozen quests. At any given time, one of them should be in your quests log.

Comment: @Omegacron yes but there's loads of quests in there, I was hoping there may be some way to tell which is the "story".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Out of Time

Jewel of the Commonwealth

Unlikely Valentine

Getting a Clue

Reunions

Dangerous Minds

The Glowing Sea

Hunter/Hunted

The Molecular Level

Institutionalized

Here are the main quest names. Depending on where you are in the story, your pip boy should have one of these quests in it.

No, you won't be able to tell which quest is the main one. You'll just have to remember which one starts up or come back to this list.

Comment: Good answer. You may want to add a spoiler tag stating that the main quests are all centered around finding you-know-who.

Comment: This covers Act 1 and 2, but not faction-specific quests of Act 3.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault The list of story quests will vary among playthroughs at that point, so this seems like the best list.

Comment: If you want to cover Act 3, just look up the lists of quests of the faction that you sided with. I agree with @DCShannon which is why I only included the  main quest without spoiling the rest.